# How can I determine when the network stack is ready to open socket to same host/port again?

Tags: c++, c, sockets, posix, berkeley-sockets

I have the following C program whose main function `runTCPConnectivityCheck` opens a TCP socket, sends a string of bytes to it and closes it:

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static int runTCPConnectivityCheck(const int port)
{
    int fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (fd < 0)
    {
        printf("socket failed\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int reuseAddrTrue = 1;
    if (setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &reuseAddrTrue, sizeof(reuseAddrTrue)) != 0)
    {
        printf("setsockopt failed\n");
        return 1;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr = { 0 };
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(port);

    if (inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &serv_addr.sin_addr) != 1)
    {
        printf("inet_pton failed\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (connect(fd, (struct sockaddr*)(&serv_addr), sizeof(serv_addr)) != 0)
    {
        printf("connect failed\n");
        return 1;
    }

    const char* message = "hello";
    const size_t messageLength = strlen(message);
    if (send(fd, message, messageLength, 0) != messageLength)
    {
        printf("send failed\n");
        return 1;
    }

    shutdown(fd, SHUT_RDWR);
    close(fd);

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        printf("%s\n", runTCPConnectivityCheck(5555) == 0 ? "success" : "failure");
        //sleep(1);
    }
}
```

If I attempt to test the same port repeatedly, the first call to `runTCPConnectivityCheck` works just fine but all subsequent calls fail on the call to `connect`. If I add the call to `sleep` in, then it also works. Presumably, the 1-second delay gives the network stack sufficient time to clean up the socket so that I can connect to the same port again.

First of all: Am I shutting the socket down properly? Secondly: If I am shutting it down properly, what is the standard way to determine when the network stack is ready to connect to the same host and port again (instead of the lame `sleep` I'm using currently)?

**Update**

More details: `connect` is failing with error code 61 or `ECONNREFUSED` while `strerror` is returning "Connection refused".

The server in this case is the `netstat`/`nc` command running in a loop on the same machine as the test program:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
  nc -l 5555
done
```

Program is now C, for real.

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong. Instead I would say that it's a problem in the peer you connect to, that it doesn't properly handle closed connections.

Comment: However, it would be helpful if you printed the value of `errno` if any system function (like `connect`, `send` etc.) fails. Or use `strerror` to get a printable string of the error, or print it using `perror`. Just so you know *what* the error is. Please do that, and then edit your question to include the error.

Comment: Do try and get out of the habit of `using namespace std`. That namespace prefix exists for a reason.

Comment: @NominalAnimal This has a lot of C++ stream code in it.

Comment: your code is fine, its the server thats suspect

Comment: I can easily imagine that server might throttle connections by requiring a certain quite time between connection attempts.

Comment: Details updated: `connect` is returning `ECONNREFUSED`. The server is `nc` running locally.

Comment: Program is also now legit C.

Comment: Are you missing SO_REUSEADDR?

Comment: @MarkSetchell: I've added a call to `setsockopt`. This doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: `SO_REUSEADDR` is a good point, but should in almost all cases not be needed for a client-type application or connection. It should almost always only be needed for the server-side. Also, only a single second should not be enough for the TCP state `TIME_WAIT` (which is what `SO_REUSEADDR` is used to bypass).

Comment: Can you run `nc` in verbose mode (add the `-v` flag, or possible `-vv` to be extra verbose)? What does it say?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Unfortunately, it looks like neither `-v` nor `-vv` do anything with the version of `nc` running on my Mac. I agree with the general opinion that it's probably something on the server side. I've just hacked together a simple Python echo server and my client works just fine with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general consensus is that there is nothing particularly wrong with the client code. It turns out that my test server is not able to keep up with my client:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
  nc -l 5555
done
```

I wrote a forking server in Python which is able to service all of the client connections without difficulty.